# How can I make “ng serve” wait for “ng build” to finish using a ng library?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-devkit

The problem in doing so, is that ng serve starts reloading as soon as ng build starts recompiling, so after each file change it refreshes the browser ~3 times and often doesn't show the new changes in the browser window until a 4th (manual) refresh.

Comment: are you using 'serve' and 'build' both simultaneously ?

Comment: yes I'm running the build for all my library packages and then at the same time i'm running the serve for the demo app

Comment: May I know why you would need to run both commands simultaneously?

Comment: why so, what is your use case ?

Comment: turn off autosave in vscode and disable cache in dev tools in browser

Comment: We are developing components (ng build) and are using the demo app (ng serve) to use these components inside our (demo) app

Comment: @WiselyDCruizer I don't use vscode ;)

Comment: are these same app, could you elaborate little more ?

Comment: We are using a mono-repo,

containing multiple components and a demo

like :
`
    - demo
    - packages
        - component1
        - component2
`

And we are running `ng build` for each component and `ng serve` for our demo app

Comment: hmmm formatting is not as it should :(

Comment: could you create a minimal git repo for demo purpose ? and steps you are using to run your app.

Answer (score -1):

You can use just this command : `ng serve --aot`  it contains ng serve and ng build inside

Comment: No, --aot is just a ahead of time compilation flag, it doesn't generate deployable files

Comment: before leaving a negative point, please make sure what is the F... question. thank you.